# How to define/iterate over nested property lists in LaTeX3

Tags: latex3

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fna{mm}{
  \typeout{#1}
  \typeout{#2}

  \NewDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fnb{mm}{
    \typeout{#1}
    \typeout{#2}
  }

  \prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:b \my:mapper:fnb
}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:a}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooa} {baza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {foob} {bazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooc} {bazc}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:b}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooa} {yaza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xoob} {yazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooc} {yazc}

\prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:a \my:mapper:fna

\end{document}
```

It errors at this point however:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined"
!
! Command '\my:mapper:fnb' already defined!
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.35 \prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:a \my:mapper:fna
```

I am not sure what is wrong because the definition is created only one time just before the `\prop_map_function` call. Wondering how to fix this so I can do nested function calls where the nested function call can potentially use `#1` and such from parent scopes.

*Note*, it does work if the command is moved outside of the nesting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fnb{mm}{
  \typeout{#1}
  \typeout{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fna{mm}{
  \typeout{#1}
  \typeout{#2}

  \prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:b \my:mapper:fnb
}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:a}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooa} {baza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {foob} {bazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooc} {bazc}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:b}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooa} {yaza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xoob} {yazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooc} {yazc}

\prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:a \my:mapper:fna

\end{document}
```

But I would like to do it the original way if possible.

Comment: In case you are not aware, you are not using the naming conventions of expl3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is wrong

- You define a command you already defined. And `\NewDocumentCommand` is supposed to throw an error if a command is already defined. At this point you could use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`  and would not encounter that problem.
- You use `#1` in the inner function (so that you will never use the content from property list `b`). To call arguments of a function that is defined within a function prepend a `#` for the level of nesting (so `##1` in this case).
- You are abusing expl3 concepts like function signatures. A `:N` means that *one token* is expected (a control word), so you should not group it. In practice that means you should replace `\prop_new:N {\my:pl:a}` by `\prop_new:N \my:pl:a`.
- You are introducing own naming conventions which make code kind of unreadable and bad style. The expl3 naming scheme for variables would be `\<local or global>_[_]<module>_<variable>_<type>`, e.g. `\l_pollard_a_prop`. For control sequences you would use `\[__]<module>_<name>:<signature>`, e.g. `\pollard_mapper_fna:nn` which has a valid signatures taking two groups.
- You are mixing different levels of interface. The code level (expl3) syntax (completely different than intended) and the document level syntax (xparse). Your `\NewDocumentCommand`s should probably be internal (i.e. `\cs_new:Npn`).

## Why it is happening

A wrapper function is called on each item, but even after the first one the function is already defined. That means you are using `\my:wrapper:fna` on each item which tries to define `\my:wrapper:fnb` as a new command at each invocation. This throws the documented error.

The wrong output is caused by your usage of `#1` instead of `##1`. So you should replace this.

## Would I recommend using `\DeclareDocumentCommand`?

No, because you are using a wrapper function on the entire property list b each time you call the wrapper for a.

## Better code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_pollard_a_prop
\prop_new:N \l_pollard_b_prop
\cs_new:Npn \pollard_wrappera:nn #1#2
    {
      \noindent #1\\
      #2\\
      \cs_set:Npn \pollard_wrapperb:nn ##1##2
            {
                \noindent
                - ##1\\
            - ##2\par
            }
      \prop_map_function:NN \l_pollard_b_prop \pollard_wrapperb:nn
    }

\NewDocumentCommand { \puttopropa } { m m }
    {
        \prop_put:Nnn \l_pollard_a_prop { #1 } { #2 }
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \puttopropb } { m m }
    {
        \prop_put:Nnn \l_pollard_b_prop { #1 } { #2 }
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \processlista } { }
    {
        \prop_map_function:NN \l_pollard_a_prop \pollard_wrappera:nn
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\puttopropa{fooa}{baza}
\puttopropa{foob}{bazb}
\puttopropa{fooc}{bazc}
\puttopropb{xooa}{yaza}
\puttopropb{xoob}{yazb}
\puttopropb{xooc}{yazc}
\processlista
\end{document}
```

## Your code (compilable)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fna{mm}{
  \typeout{#1}
  \typeout{#2}

  \DeclareDocumentCommand\my:mapper:fnb{mm}{
    \typeout{##1}
    \typeout{##2}
  }

  \prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:b \my:mapper:fnb

}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:a}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooa} {baza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {foob} {bazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:a {fooc} {bazc}

\prop_new:N {\my:pl:b}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooa} {yaza}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xoob} {yazb}
\prop_put:Nnn \my:pl:b {xooc} {yazc}

\prop_map_function:NN \my:pl:a \my:mapper:fna

\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus `\prop_new:N {\my:pl:a}`, plus `\my:mapper:fnb` using `#1 #2` instead `##1 ##2`, plus the naming conventions.

Comment: In relation to your last point in the first section, I am confused as to why: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422985/when-to-create-a-new-function-vs-a-command-in-latex3

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the little details, it helps in learning how to do this. I am seeing just how fine-grained all the syntax is which I overlooked initially.

Comment: @LancePollard See my update.

Comment: @Manuel Did I miss anything?

Comment: @TeXnician the `\cs_new` and `\cs_set` should be `_protected`. But I don't know, I just meant to suggest that you took more points that just solve the code to be compilable :) +1