# Translating lua code into LaTeX3: how to iterate over a prop containing props?

Tags: expl3, lua

I am writing a LaTeX package to pretty-print amino acid residues and numbers with optional symbols. I have created a `lua` programme that outputs according to a customisable format, `\StyleOption{}`, using a `lua` table (the `'sl'`, `'as'` meaning short lower, abbreviation sentence-case etc.) that works as intended (there are many more residues like `ala_abbrev`, `tyr_abbrev` etc but they were pruned for this question):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
his_abbrev = {['sl'] = "h", ['su'] = "H", ['al'] = "his", ['as'] = "His", ['au'] = "HIS"}
ile_abbrev = {['sl'] = "i", ['su'] = "I", ['al'] = "ile", ['as'] = "Ile", ['au'] = "ILE"}
lys_abbrev = {['sl'] = "k", ['su'] = "K", ['al'] = "lys", ['as'] = "Lys", ['au'] = "LYS"}

amino_acid_names = {
    his_abbrev, ile_abbrev, lys_abbrev,
}

function amino_acid_name(residue, style)
  for _, table in ipairs (amino_acid_names) do
    for key, val in pairs (table) do
      if tostring (val) == residue then
        tex.print (table[style])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\StyleOption{as}

\newcommand\residueString[2]{\directlua{
  amino_acid_name ("\luaescapestring{#1}", "\luaescapestring{#2}")}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\aail}{o m m}{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{%
  \residueString{#2}{\StyleOption}%
    \textsuperscript{$\scriptstyle\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1.5mu$} $\mkern-2mu#3$%
  }{%
    \residueString{#2}{\StyleOption} $\mkern1.5mu#3$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\aail{i}{434}

\aail[*]{lys}{112}

\aail{HIS}{88}

\end{document}
```

My issue arises from trying to convert the above into LaTeX3 format. I use LuaLaTeX extensively so I am happy for the package to need `lua` but others might not. I have went through [How to define/iterate over nested property lists in LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422988) but I am not sure how to iterate over a `prop` containing `props` (`\l_abbrev_all_prop`) and whilst the [LaTeX3 Interfaces documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) probably provides the solution, it is intimidating especially when you don't know what to search for.

Question: How can I get the following LaTeX3 code to print `\ResidueString` according to the key defined in `\StyleOption` similar to the `lua` code please?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\StyleOption}{}{as} % for the key to \l_abbrev_his_prop etc

\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_his_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_ile_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_lys_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_all_prop

% to save space in Q, just putting them all on one line
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_his_prop {sl = h, su = H, al = his, as = His, au = HIS}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_ile_prop {sl = i, su = I, al = ile, as = Ile, au = ILE}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_lys_prop {sl = k, su = K, al = lys, as = Lys, au = LYS}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_all_prop
    {
    his = \l_abbrev_his_prop,
    ile = \l_abbrev_ile_prop,
    lys = \l_abbrev_lys_prop
    }

% \cs_new:Npn \residueString:nn #1#2
%     {
%         \prop_map_function:NN \l_abbrev_all_prop #1#2 % What goes here?
%     }

\NewDocumentCommand { \aail } { o m m }
    {
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \residueString{ #2 }{ \StyleOption }%
        \textsuperscript{$\scriptstyle\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1.5mu$} $\mkern-2mu#3$%
    }{%
        \residueString{ #2 }{ \StyleOption } $\mkern1.5mu#3$%
    }%
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\aail{i}{434}

\aail[*]{lys}{112}

\aail{HIS}{88}

\end{document}
```

Note: this will all be customisable including adding custom residues, kern distances, sub/super-script, float caption options set in package options/`\SetResidueOptions{key=val}` etc but this is just a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

A fairly literal translation of the Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\StyleOption}{}{as} % for the key to \l_abbrev_his_prop etc

\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_his_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_ile_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_lys_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_all_prop

% to save space in Q, just putting them all on one line
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_his_prop {sl = h, su = H, al = his, as = His, au = HIS}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_ile_prop {sl = i, su = I, al = ile, as = Ile, au = ILE}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_lys_prop {sl = k, su = K, al = lys, as = Lys, au = LYS}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_all_prop
    {
    his = \l_abbrev_his_prop,
    ile = \l_abbrev_ile_prop,
    lys = \l_abbrev_lys_prop
    }

 \cs_new:Npn \residueString:nn #1#2
     {
        \tl_set:Nx\l_residue{#1}
        \tl_set:Nx\l_style{#2}
         \prop_map_function:NN \l_abbrev_all_prop \__abbrev_aux:nn
     }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\prop_item:Nn{Ne}
   
\cs_new:Npn \__abbrev_aux:nn #1#2
     {
         \prop_map_inline:Nn #2 {
    \tl_if_eq:NnT 
      \l_residue
       {##2}
       {\prop_item:Ne#2{\l_style}}
     }
}

   


   

\NewDocumentCommand { \aail } { o m m }
    {
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \residueString:nn{ #2 }{ \StyleOption }%
        \textsuperscript{$\scriptstyle\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1.5mu$}~  $\mkern-2mu#3$%
    }{%
        \residueString:nn{ #2 }{ \StyleOption } ~ $\mkern1.5mu#3$%
    }%
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\aail{i}{434}

\aail[*]{lys}{112}

\aail{HIS}{88}

\end{document}
```