# How to define/use local variable in environment <end> block in LaTeX3

Tags: environments, expl3, xparse

I am trying to learn how to do typesetting (delaying typesetting until later in the document), and am doing an example with recreating the `figure`. It is used like this:

```
\begin{myfigure}
  \mycaption{Foo}
\end{myfigure}
```

I would simply like to take that `\mycaption{Foo}` and place it into the `\caption` at the proper place in the document.

The full MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{mm} {
  \tl_new:N \l_myfigure_mycaption_tl

  \NewDocumentCommand{\mycaption}{m} {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_myfigure_mycaption_tl {#1}
  }

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % a latex3 way of doing if-statement would be helpful to know.
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{\l_myfigure_mycaption_tl}}
      {}
      {\caption{\l_myfigure_mycaption_tl}}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{myfigure}
  \mycaption{Foo}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

In that, I try creating the API `\mycaption` like this:

```
\tl_new:N \l_myfigure_mycaption_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycaption}{m} {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_myfigure_mycaption_tl {#1}
}
```

I am trying to make this `tl` variable a local variable to the *environment* `myfigure`. I am trying to make it so it's not created globally outside of the environment, yet I want to use it in the "after block" of the environment.

Then I check if that variable is blank, and if it is *not* blank, I typeset the caption.

The goal is to be able to:

1. Define an API variable (e.g. `\mycaption`) to use for setting a value in an environment, and
2. Plugging that value into the appropriate place later in the document flow.
3. Not sure if nesting the `\NewDocumentCommand` is correct (as per the comments under this answer: [How to define nested environments and commands in LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423107/how-to-define-nested-environments-and-commands-in-latex3/423113#423113))

This is essentially a getter/setter approach, so I'm wondering if this is the correct approach or there is a better alternative. If there is a better alternative that would be good to know, otherwise just knowing how to accomplish it using the approach I have outlined is helpful as well.

The caption shows up blank in my MWE.

Comment: By using the `\l_....` syntax the 'variables' aren't local. You have to use the `\....set:...` macros and `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` to keep their values local, i.e. in a group. `\tl_new:N` in a macro that is called repeatedly is bad, however, since it will complain at the 2nd usage

Comment: if you find yourself nesting `\NewDocumentCommand` calls then most likely something is wrong, that should almost always just be the declaration of the top level document syntax.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was wondering about that in the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423113/26407. I was able to get it working with nested `\NewDocumentCommand`, but don't understand (a) why that works and (b) why that's wrong. Maybe related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422985/best-practices-on-when-to-create-a-new-function-vs-a-command-in-latex3

Comment: `\tl_if_empty:NF \l_myfigure_my_caption {foo}` is what you want for the `\ifthenelse` ... test

Comment: There's another problem here: Using `\tl_set:Nn` inside of the doubled nested `figure\tikzpicture` won't work to make the content of the `\l_myfigure...tl` variable alive after `\end{tikzpicture}`, since `\mycaption` is effectively called inside the `tikzpicture` environment. It is local, but then lost after `tikzpicture`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer woohoo thank you! That's what the problem was. I've had this problem for many days in many different contexts. Now how to fix it, I'm not sure what to do. That description helps better understand the problem though.

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language so "really" everything is a macro and just works by inline text replacement, there is no function stack or compiler in the sense of a compiled language. So lots of things "work" if you use them in ways that are not as designed as making them not work is prohibitively expensive,  but the NewDocumentxxx declaration sare by design just intended for top level document declarations.

Comment: please don't edit the question to include an entirely different issue (the dead cycles count) after answers have been posted. It makes the archived question/answer much harder to understand.

Comment: you have defined the `myfigure` enviornment to take two arguments `\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{mm} {` so in the use the first argument is `\caption` and the second argument is `Foo` but all three answers have already posted fixed versions of the declaration.

Comment: @LancePollard in my answer I just use gset  to save the single caption text but of you want to stack multiple  calls use for example seq_put_right  as i used to stack environment  names in the earlier question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an optional third argument that holds the caption title and testing with `\IfValueT{#3}{...}`.

No need for `\tl...` code, in my point of view...

Also possible: Apply a `key-value` interface here for providing more options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}





\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{mmo} {%

  #1%
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    }{%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % a latex3 way of doing if-statement would be helpful to know.
    \IfValueT{#3}{%
      \caption{#3}%
    }%
  \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{myfigure}{Stuff}{}[foo]
\end{myfigure}


\begin{myfigure}{Otherstuff}{}
\end{myfigure}


\end{document}
```

**Alternative solution, by storing the arguments locally**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_lance_mycaption_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycaption}{+m}{%
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_lance_mycaption_tl {#1}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{mm} {%
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_lance_mycaption_tl
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    }{%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_lance_mycaption_tl {\caption{\tl_use:N \l_lance_mycaption_tl}}
  \end{figure}
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \l_lance_mycaption_tl  \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\begin{myfigure}{Stuff}{}
  \mycaption{Foo}
\end{myfigure}


\ExplSyntaxOn
Value\space of\space variable: \tl_use:N \l_lance_mycaption_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{myfigure}{Otherstuff}{}
  \mycaption{Foobar}
\end{myfigure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @LancePollard the variable approach is what I showed (although for the particular case of caption using an argument as in this answer would be better)

Comment: @LancePollard: See the update at the end of the post please

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycaption}{m} {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_myfigure_mycaption_tl {#1}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_myfigure_mycaption_tl {}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tl_if_empty:NTF\g_myfigure_mycaption_tl
      {}
      {\caption{\g_myfigure_mycaption_tl}}
  \end{figure}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{myfigure}
  \mycaption{Foo}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like for the `\mycaption` to only be usable/defined within the `\myfigure` scope.

Comment: @LancePollard Add a boolean to the start of the environment and test for that (cf. how things like `\mathtt` work).

Comment: @LancePollard that is almost certainly a mistake:-) You could define it like the standard `\caption` which explicitly tests that the current environment is a float and generates an error otherwise, but that just makes someone write a very popular capt-of package that is used in multiple answers here that simply subverts that test and lets you use captions anywhere.

Comment: @LancePollard or as in Christian's answer don't have a `\mycaption` at all and make it an optional argument of the environment

Comment: So then there is no community-accepted way of defining nested environments/commands it sounds like.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that could work, but that doesn't solve the problem since I would like to use this approach for other more complicated examples.

Comment: @LancePollard there are ways, but generally it is bad style to do so and it is better to make the commands globally defined whenever possible.

Comment: @LancePollard  "more complicated examples" isn't a description that can be answered. If you have a different example you could ask a different question, but the point of the last couple of answers is that your complicated examples have simpler solutions than you expect oif you go with the flow and use latex idioms rather than trying to translate idioms from javascript or other languages.

Comment: latex is the first language i've encountered where global variables are _good_ :)

Comment: @LancePollard you want to look at DEK's pascal source of  tex-the-program:-)

Answer (score 1):

You end up with `\mycaption` in the middle of a `tikzpicture` environment.

I'm not sure what the gain is in doing so and hiding `tikzpicture` which you can't pass options to.

Anyway, the simplest approach is to specify the caption at the beginning. Other options can be defined and set.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { pollard/figure }
 {
  caption      .tl_set:N = \l_myfigure_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_myfigure_caption_lof_tl,
  label        .tl_set:N = \l_myfigure_label_tl,
  align .choice:,
  align/left   .code:n = \raggedright,
  align/right  .code:n = \raggedleft,
  align/center .code:n = \centering,
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myfigure}{O{}}
 {
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \keys_set:nn { pollard/figure } { align=center, #1 }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 }
 {
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_myfigure_caption_tl
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_myfigure_caption_lof_tl
     {
      \caption{\l_myfigure_caption_tl}
     }
     {
      \caption[\l_myfigure_caption_lof_tl]{\l_myfigure_caption_tl}
     }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_myfigure_label_tl { \label{\l_myfigure_label_tl} }
   }
  \end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Examples}

\begin{myfigure}[
  caption=Foo,
]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{myfigure}

\begin{myfigure}[
  caption=Foo but with baz,
  shortcaption=Baz,
  label=foobaz,
  align=left,
]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

However, I can't see the advantage over

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption[Baz]{Foo but with baz}\label{foobaz}

\end{figure}
```

[image]